# How do I uninstall Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, xfce

My Nan was originally on Windows XP so I changed it to Ubuntu. She had problems using it so I changed it to Xubuntu (as I could make it look similar to Windows and she woul d find it easier to use. But then she bought a new computer and gave me this one, but I want it back to Ubuntu. How do I do this?

Comment: Small tip. In Ubuntu Software Center there's an app called Classic Menu.  It is something similar to start menu in XP. Just so you can make a user feel at home next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

First check if the Ubuntu Unity interface isn't still installed by clicking on the Ubuntu logo next to your name in the log-in screen. Maybe the Unity interface is still installed.

[This post](http://www.linux.org/threads/converting-between-the-ubuntus.5079/) explains exactly how to change between different versions of *buntu. The easiest way would be to install Ubuntu Desktop before removing Xubuntu Desktop (if you want to remove it, you can  also keep both Ubuntu and Xubuntu installed so you can switch at will, but you will have a lot of (double) software installed and use more HDD space.)